# Trying to take an ATOM feed and parse out a section written in XHTML in XSLT format

Tags: xslt, atom-feed

I am trying to take an NOAA RSS feed (NOAA site says it uses ATOM and CAPS) and convert it for SharePoint using XSLT.  I am new to this and have limited experience working in XSLT.  Here is a sample of the feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" 
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
<id>urn:uuid:9ae4ae29-830f-4870-bace-0f70984b76bd</id><title>        
TSUNAMI INFORMATION STATEMENT NUMBER   1        </title>
<updated>2022-01-29T03:00:32Z</updated>
<author>
  <name>NWS PACIFIC TSUNAMI WARNING CENTER HONOLULU HI</name>
 <uri>http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/</uri>
 <email>ntwc@noaa.gov</email>
 </author>
 <icon>http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/images/favicon.ico</icon>
 <link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" title="self" 
 href="http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/events/xml/PAAQAtom.xml"/>
 <link rel="related" title="Energy Map"  
 <entry>
 <title>KERMADEC ISLANDS REGION</title><updated>2022-01-29T03:00:32Z</updated>
 <geo:lat>-29.751</geo:lat>
 <geo:long>-174.709</geo:long>
 <summary type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <strong>Category:</strong> Information<br/>
    <strong>Bulletin Issue Time: </strong> 2022.01.29 03:00:32 UTC 
    <br/><strong>Preliminary Magnitude: </strong>6.6(Mwp)<br/> 
    <strong>Lat/Lon: </strong>-29.751 / -174.709<br/>
    <strong>Affected Region: </strong>KERMADEC ISLANDS REGION<br/>
</div>
</summary>
</entry>
</feed>
```

My problem is trying to convert the "summary type=xhtml" section into a readable format (like below) instead of a long run-on sentence.

```
CATEGORY: Information
BULLETIN ISSUE TIME: 
PRELIMINARY MAGNITUDE:
```

Can someone provide me with some suggestions on how to parse the information in XSLT?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: <summary type="xhtml"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <strong>Category:</strong> Information<br/><strong>Bulletin Issue Time: </strong> 2022.01.29 03:00:32 UTC <br/><strong>Preliminary Magnitude: </strong>6.6(Mwp)<br/><strong>Lat/Lon: </strong>-29.751 / -174.709<br/>
  <strong>Affected Region: </strong>KERMADEC ISLANDS REGION<br/><b>Note:</b>  <br/><strong>Definition: </strong><a href="http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/events/PHEB/2022/01/29/22029000/1/WEGM42/WEGM42.txt">View bulletin</a><img src="http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/events/PHEB/2022/01/29/22029000/1/WEGM42/ " alt="Energy Map" />

Comment: That `<div/>`, rendered by a web browser, looks almost exactly like your suggested format. What specific problem are you seeing?

Comment: The input you show is not a well-formed XML document . The 2nd `link` element is unclosed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no standard format for the contents of an Atom `summary`. If your data provider adheres to the format shown in your example, then -  given a **well-formed XML** input such as:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" 
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
<id>urn:uuid:9ae4ae29-830f-4870-bace-0f70984b76bd</id><title>        
TSUNAMI INFORMATION STATEMENT NUMBER   1        </title>
<updated>2022-01-29T03:00:32Z</updated>
<author>
  <name>NWS PACIFIC TSUNAMI WARNING CENTER HONOLULU HI</name>
 <uri>http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/</uri>
 <email>ntwc@noaa.gov</email>
 </author>
 <icon>http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/images/favicon.ico</icon>
 <link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" title="self" 
 href="http://ntwc.arh.noaa.gov/events/xml/PAAQAtom.xml"/>
 <entry>
 <title>KERMADEC ISLANDS REGION</title><updated>2022-01-29T03:00:32Z</updated>
 <geo:lat>-29.751</geo:lat>
 <geo:long>-174.709</geo:long>
 <summary type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <strong>Category:</strong> Information<br/>
    <strong>Bulletin Issue Time: </strong> 2022.01.29 03:00:32 UTC 
    <br/><strong>Preliminary Magnitude: </strong>6.6(Mwp)<br/> 
    <strong>Lat/Lon: </strong>-29.751 / -174.709<br/>
    <strong>Affected Region: </strong>KERMADEC ISLANDS REGION<br/>
</div>
</summary>
</entry>
</feed>
```

you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/a:feed">
    <xsl:for-each select="a:entry/a:summary/x:div/x:strong">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[1])" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
Category:Information
Bulletin Issue Time: 2022.01.29 03:00:32 UTC
Preliminary Magnitude: 6.6(Mwp)
Lat/Lon: -29.751 / -174.709
Affected Region: KERMADEC ISLANDS REGION
```